# Android Studio Backup and reinstall For Windows

Tags: android-studio

I am about to format my pc and clean install windows, since android studio is not an easy software to install as it does install several other components at the time installation.
My Question is that is there anyway I can take backup of the complete software and its components and reinstall without changing anything?